# Why is ffmpeg biased when converting to 16-bit integer or 32-bit float RGB output?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

Consider the following Python invocations, that exercise ffmpeg's ability to convert a 8-bit input into 16-bit integer values or 32-bit float values:

```py
import cv2
import subprocess
import numpy as np

ffmpeg = "ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -y"
flags = "-sws_flags accurate_rnd+bitexact+full_chroma_int+neighbor -sws_dither none"

for input_color_range in ("tv", "pc"):

    # Generate YUV444 video and encode it losslessly
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -color_range {input_color_range} -f lavfi -i yuvtestsrc {flags} -pix_fmt yuv444p -color_range {input_color_range} -x264-params qp=0 -frames 1 -c:v libx264 video_temp.mp4")

    # Extract YUV444 frame, as well as 8-bit int, 16-bit int and 32-bit float frame
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -f rawvideo video_temp_444_frame1.yuv")
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -color_range pc -pix_fmt rgb24 video_temp_444_frame1_8u.png")
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -color_range pc -pix_fmt rgb48be video_temp_444_frame1_16u.png")
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -color_range pc -pix_fmt gbrpf32be -f rawvideo video_temp_444_frame1_32f.gbrpf32be")

    # Reead these frames into (height, width, 3) Numpy arrays containing YUV or RGB data
    data_8u = cv2.imread("video_temp_444_frame1_8u.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[..., ::-1]
    data_16u = cv2.imread("video_temp_444_frame1_16u.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[..., ::-1]
    data_yuv = np.rollaxis(np.frombuffer(open("video_temp_444_frame1.yuv", "rb").read()).view(np.uint8).reshape((3, 240, 320)), 0, 3).copy()
    data_32f = np.rollaxis(np.frombuffer(open("video_temp_444_frame1_32f.gbrpf32be", "rb").read()).view(np.dtype(">f4")).reshape((3, 240, 320)), 0, 3).copy()
    data_32f[..., (0, 1, 2)] = data_32f[..., (2, 0, 1)]

    # This pixel in yuvtestsrc corresponds to limited-range YUV=(235, 128,
    # 128)=(100%, 0.0, 0.0), which should correspond to 100% white, i.e.
    # RGB=(100%, 100%, 100%).
    if input_color_range == "tv":
        i, j = 10, 294
    # This pixel in yuvtestsrc corresponds to full-range YUV=(255, 128,
    # 128)=(100%, 0.0, 0.0), which should correspond to 100% white, i.e.
    # RGB=(100%, 100%, 100%).
    elif input_color_range == "pc":
        i, j = 10, 319
    else:
        raise Exception(input_color_range)

    # Print pixel values
    print("")
    print(f"Values for {input_color_range}-range input video at ({i}, {j}):")
    print("- 8-bit YUV input   = %s" % data_yuv[i, j, :])
    print("- 8-bit RGB output  = %s (= %s)" % (data_8u[i, j, :], data_8u[i, j, :] / 255))
    print("- 16-bit RGB output = %s (= %s)" % (data_16u[i, j, :], data_16u[i, j, :] / 65535))
    print("- Float RGB output  = %s" % data_32f[i, j, :])
```

The script first generates a video frame from ffmpeg's YUV test source, encoded with no chroma subsampling (4:4:4) as losslessly as possible.

That video is then used as a reference source to extract the following frames:

- The input reference YUV data
- A 8-bit RGB conversion
- A 16-bit RGB conversion
- A 32-bit floating-point RGB conversion

One pixel is extracted from each frame, which should contain a 100% white value. The output of the last series of print statements is the following:

```
Values for tv-range input video at (10, 294):
- 8-bit YUV input   = [235 128 128]
- 8-bit RGB output  = [255 255 255] (= [1. 1. 1.])
- 16-bit RGB output = [65283 65283 65283] (= [0.99615473 0.99615473 0.99615473])
- Float RGB output  = [0.9961547 0.9961547 0.9961547]

Values for pc-range input video at (10, 319):
- 8-bit YUV input   = [255 128 128]
- 8-bit RGB output  = [255 255 255] (= [1. 1. 1.])
- 16-bit RGB output = [65280 65280 65280] (= [0.99610895 0.99610895 0.99610895])
- Float RGB output  = [0.99610895 0.99610895 0.99610895]
```

While the 8-bit RGB output values are correct, none of the others correctly output a 100% white signal. Why is that?

Comment: Try using `-pix_fmt rgb48le` (use Little Endian instead of Big Endian). It would be strange if the endianness of those numbers was the issue, but you never know...

Comment: @VC.One Just tested, the output is the same.

Comment: This was in fact a known bug, just a little hard to find: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7978. I'm a little unsure as to whether I should close this question or not.

Comment: Just use zscale.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников zscale seems to provide the correct values in that case, I added a test script. Is there a way for it to pick up the input video's color tags automatically? Or do you have to always specify them manually?

Comment: There is a way, there is input option for all: range, matrix, primaries, transfer. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zscale-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post the results of my investigation, hoping it will shed some light into what's happening inside ffmpeg for people who come upon this answer.

I added 3 different implementations of the conversion logic from raw Y'UV values (see below):

1. The original ffmpeg pipeline from `libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c`. Should yield the exact same values as those extracted using `ffmpeg.exe`.
2. The original ffmpeg pipeline, implemented using floating-point math instead of integer operations. Should yield the exact same values, up to rounding.
3. A corrected pipeline using correct scaling, implemented using floating-point math.

---

Applying [1] to the same signals as the question above yields the exact same values, which confirms that this is where ffmpeg does the potentially wrong conversions:

```py
>>> print("YUV (limited-range)  : 235 128 128")
... print("RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_16bit_pipeline(235, 128, 128, False, 8))
... print("RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *np.floor(np.array(yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_16bit_pipeline(235, 128, 128, False, 8))/256).tolist())
... print("")
... print("YUV (full-range)     : 255 128 128")
... print("RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_16bit_pipeline(255, 128, 128, True, 8))
... print("RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *np.floor(np.array(yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_16bit_pipeline(255, 128, 128, True, 8))/256).tolist())
... print("")

YUV (limited range)  :  235 128 128
RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   :  65283.0 65283.0 65283.0
RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   :  255.0 255.0 255.0

YUV (full range)     :  255 128 128
RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   :  65280.0 65280.0 65280.0
RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   :  255.0 255.0 255.0
```

A subsequent question is : what is causing these 16-bit values to be different from 65535? Are the differences caused by a rounding operation inside of this pipeline, or are the coefficients and scaling factors wrong in the first place?

---

[2] lets us prove the first hypothesis false, since it outputs the same values using only floating-point math, up to rounding:

```py
>>> print("YUV (limited-range)  : 235 128 128")
... print("RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_float_pipeline(235, 128, 128, False, 8))
... print("RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *np.floor(np.array(yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_float_pipeline(235, 128, 128, False, 8))/256).tolist())
... print("")
... print("YUV (full-range)     : 255 128 128")
... print("RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_float_pipeline(255, 128, 128, True, 8))
... print("RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *np.floor(np.array(yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_float_pipeline(255, 128, 128, True, 8))/256).tolist())

YUV (limited-range)  : 235 128 128
RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   :  65283.0 65283.0 65283.0
RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   :  255.0 255.0 255.0

YUV (full-range)     : 255 128 128
RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   :  65280.5 65280.5 65280.5
RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   :  255.0 255.0 255.0
```

---

Finally, [3] is a slightly modified version of the float pipeline using the same Y'UV to RGB conversion coefficients, but removing the unneeded bit shifts and replacing the 256/65536 multiplicative factor used to convert from 8-bit to 16-bit values to 255/65535. This indeed yields the correct full-range RGB signal at 65535 for 100% signal.

```py
>>> print("YUV (limited-range)  : 235 128 128")
... print("RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_full_float_pipeline_correct(235, 128, 128, False, 8))
... print("RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *np.floor(np.array(yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_full_float_pipeline_correct(235, 128, 128, False, 8))/256).tolist())
... print("")
... print("YUV (full-range)     : 255 128 128")
... print("RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_full_float_pipeline_correct(255, 128, 128, True, 8))
... print("RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   : ", *np.floor(np.array(yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_full_float_pipeline_correct(255, 128, 128, True, 8))/256).tolist())

YUV (limited-range)  : 235 128 128
RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   :  65535.0 65535.0 65535.0
RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   :  255.0 255.0 255.0

YUV (full-range)     : 255 128 128
RGB48 (ffmpeg int)   :  65535.0 65535.0 65535.0
RGB24 (ffmpeg int)   :  255.0 255.0 255.0
```

---

Additionally, here is the working version with `zscale`:

```py
import cv2
import subprocess
import numpy as np

ffmpeg = "ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -y"
flags = "-sws_flags accurate_rnd+bitexact+full_chroma_int+neighbor -sws_dither none"

for input_color_range in ("tv", "pc"):

    # Generate YUV444 video and encode it losslessly
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -color_range {input_color_range} -f lavfi -i yuvtestsrc {flags} -pix_fmt yuv444p -color_range {input_color_range} -colorspace bt2020nc -x264-params qp=0 -frames 1 -c:v libx264 video_temp.mp4", shell=True)

    # Extract YUV444 frame, as well as 8-bit int, 16-bit int and 32-bit float frame
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -f rawvideo video_temp_444_frame1.yuv", shell=True)
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -vf zscale,format=gbrp16le -color_range pc -pix_fmt rgb24 video_temp_444_frame1_8u.png", shell=True)
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -vf zscale,format=gbrp16le -color_range pc -pix_fmt rgb48be video_temp_444_frame1_16u.png", shell=True)
    subprocess.check_call(rf"{ffmpeg} -y {flags} -i video_temp.mp4 {flags} -vf zscale,format=gbrp16le -color_range pc -pix_fmt gbrpf32be -f rawvideo video_temp_444_frame1_32f.gbrpf32be", shell=True)

    # Reead these frames into (height, width, 3) Numpy arrays containing YUV or RGB data
    data_8u = cv2.imread("video_temp_444_frame1_8u.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[..., ::-1]
    data_16u = cv2.imread("video_temp_444_frame1_16u.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[..., ::-1]
    data_yuv = np.rollaxis(np.frombuffer(open("video_temp_444_frame1.yuv", "rb").read()).view(np.uint8).reshape((3, 240, 320)), 0, 3).copy()
    data_32f = np.rollaxis(np.frombuffer(open("video_temp_444_frame1_32f.gbrpf32be", "rb").read()).view(np.dtype(">f4")).reshape((3, 240, 320)), 0, 3).copy()
    data_32f[..., (0, 1, 2)] = data_32f[..., (2, 0, 1)]

    # This pixel in yuvtestsrc corresponds to limited-range YUV=(235, 128,
    # 128)=(100%, 0.0, 0.0), which should correspond to 100% white, i.e.
    # RGB=(100%, 100%, 100%).
    if input_color_range == "tv":
        i, j = 10, 294
    # This pixel in yuvtestsrc corresponds to full-range YUV=(255, 128,
    # 128)=(100%, 0.0, 0.0), which should correspond to 100% white, i.e.
    # RGB=(100%, 100%, 100%).
    elif input_color_range == "pc":
        i, j = 10, 319
    else:
        raise Exception(input_color_range)

    # Print pixel values
    print("")
    print(f"Values for {input_color_range}-range input video at ({i}, {j}):")
    print("- 8-bit YUV input   = %s" % data_yuv[i, j, :])
    print("- 8-bit RGB output  = %s (= %s)" % (data_8u[i, j, :], data_8u[i, j, :] / 255))
    print("- 16-bit RGB output = %s (= %s)" % (data_16u[i, j, :], data_16u[i, j, :] / 65535))
    print("- Float RGB output  = %s" % data_32f[i, j, :])
```

The values are indeed correct:

```py
Values for tv-range input video at (10, 294):
- 8-bit YUV input   = [235 128 128]
- 8-bit RGB output  = [255 255 255] (= [1. 1. 1.])
- 16-bit RGB output = [65535 65535 65535] (= [1. 1. 1.])
- Float RGB output  = [0.99998474 1.         1.        ]

Values for pc-range input video at (10, 319):
- 8-bit YUV input   = [255 128 128]
- 8-bit RGB output  = [255 255 255] (= [1. 1. 1.])
- 16-bit RGB output = [65535 65535 65535] (= [1. 1. 1.])
- Float RGB output  = [0.99998474 1.         1.        ]
```

---

[1] Original pipeline used in ffmpeg `gbrpf32` conversion routine:

```py
def yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_16bit_pipeline(pY, pU, pV, fullRange, depth):

    # Coefficients for ITU-R BT.2020 NCL
    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_coeffs:58 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    crv, cbu, cgu, cgv = 110013, 140363, 12277, 42626

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:roundToInt16:762 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    def roundToInt16(f: np.int64) -> np.int16:
        r = (f + (np.int64(1) << 15)) >> 16
        if r < -0x7FFF:
            return np.int16(0x8000)
        elif r > 0x7FFF:
            return np.int16(0x7FFF)
        return np.int16(r)

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:813 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    cy = np.int64(1) << 16
    oy = np.int64(0)

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:817 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    if not fullRange:
        cy = (cy * 255) // 219
        oy = np.int64(16) << 16
    else:
        crv = (crv * 224) // 255
        cbu = (cbu * 224) // 255
        cgu = (cgu * 224) // 255
        cgv = (cgv * 224) // 255

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:811 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    cgu = -cgu
    cgv = -cgv

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:836 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    yuv2rgb_y_coeff = roundToInt16(cy * (np.int64(1) << 13))
    yuv2rgb_y_offset = roundToInt16(oy * (np.int64(1) <<  9))
    yuv2rgb_v2r_coeff = roundToInt16(crv * (np.int64(1) << 13))
    yuv2rgb_v2g_coeff = roundToInt16(cgv * (np.int64(1) << 13))
    yuv2rgb_u2g_coeff = roundToInt16(cgu * (np.int64(1) << 13))
    yuv2rgb_u2b_coeff = roundToInt16(cbu * (np.int64(1) << 13))

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2389 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    Y = -np.int64(0x40000000)
    U = -(np.int64(128) << 23)
    V = -(np.int64(128) << 23)

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2394 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    # NOTE: Ffmpeg refers to a filter with multiple pixels, here we only add one.
    Y += np.int64(pY) << (31-depth)
    U += np.int64(pU) << (31-depth)
    V += np.int64(pV) << (31-depth)

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2402 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    Y >>= 14
    Y += 0x10000
    U >>= 14
    V >>= 14

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2417 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    Y -= yuv2rgb_y_offset
    Y *= yuv2rgb_y_coeff
    Y += 1 << 13

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2420 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    R = Y + V * yuv2rgb_v2r_coeff
    G = Y + V * yuv2rgb_v2g_coeff + U * yuv2rgb_u2g_coeff
    B = Y +                         U * yuv2rgb_u2b_coeff

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2424 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    pR = np.round(np.clip(float(R >> 14), 0, 65535), 1)
    pG = np.round(np.clip(float(G >> 14), 0, 65535), 1)
    pB = np.round(np.clip(float(B >> 14), 0, 65535), 1)

    return pR, pG, pB
```

---

[2] Same as the original pipeline, but computed using floating-point math instead of integers:

```py
def yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_float_pipeline(pY, pU, pV, fullRange, depth):

    # Color space conversion coefficients for YCbCr -> RGB mapping.
    #
    #   Comment from libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:
    #
    #   Entries are {crv, cbu, cgu, cgv}
    #
    #     crv = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (1 - cr) / 0.5
    #     cbu = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (1 - cb) / 0.5
    #     cgu = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (cb / cg) * (1 - cb) / 0.5
    #     cgv = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (cr / cg) * (1 - cr) / 0.5
    #
    #   where Y = cr * R + cg * G + cb * B and cr + cg + cb = 1.
    #
    # Compute the crv, cbu, cgu and cgv coefficients in float, with the same
    # scaling as ffmpeg.
    cr, cb = 0.2627, 0.0593
    cg = 1.0 - cr - cb
    fcrv = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (1 - cr) / 0.5
    fcbu = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (1 - cb) / 0.5
    fcgu = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (cb / cg) * (1 - cb) / 0.5
    fcgv = (255 / 224) * 65536 * (cr / cg) * (1 - cr) / 0.5

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:roundToInt16:762 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    def froundToInt16(f):
        r = np.round(float(f) / 65536.0)
        if r < -0x7FFF:
            return float(0x8000)
        elif r > 0x7FFF:
            return float(0x7FFF)
        return float(r)

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:813 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fcy = float(1 << 16)
    foy = 0.0

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:817 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    if not fullRange:
        fcy = (fcy * 255) / 219
        foy = float(16 << 16)
    else:
        fcrv = (fcrv * 224) / 255
        fcbu = (fcbu * 224) / 255
        fcgu = (fcgu * 224) / 255
        fcgv = (fcgv * 224) / 255

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:811 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fcgu = -fcgu
    fcgv = -fcgv

    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:836 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fyuv2rgb_y_coeff = froundToInt16(fcy * float(np.int64(1) << 13))
    fyuv2rgb_y_offset = froundToInt16(foy * float(np.int64(1) <<  9))
    fyuv2rgb_v2r_coeff = froundToInt16(fcrv * float(np.int64(1) << 13))
    fyuv2rgb_v2g_coeff = froundToInt16(fcgv * float(np.int64(1) << 13))
    fyuv2rgb_u2g_coeff = froundToInt16(fcgu * float(np.int64(1) << 13))
    fyuv2rgb_u2b_coeff = froundToInt16(fcbu * float(np.int64(1) << 13))

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2389 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY = -float(np.int64(128) << (31 - 8))
    fU = -float(np.int64(128) << (31 - 8))
    fV = -float(np.int64(128) << (31 - 8))

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2394 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    # NOTE: Ffmpeg refers to a filter with multiple pixels, here we only add one.
    fY += float(np.int64(pY) << (31-depth))
    fU += float(np.int64(pU) << (31-depth))
    fV += float(np.int64(pV) << (31-depth))

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2402 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY /= 2**14
    fY += 0x10000
    fU /= 2**14
    fV /= 2**14

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2417 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY -= fyuv2rgb_y_offset
    fY *= fyuv2rgb_y_coeff
    fY += 1 << 13

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2420 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fR = fY + fV * fyuv2rgb_v2r_coeff
    fG = fY + fV * fyuv2rgb_v2g_coeff + fU * fyuv2rgb_u2g_coeff
    fB = fY +                           fU * fyuv2rgb_u2b_coeff

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2424 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fR = np.round(np.clip((fR / (2**14)), 0, 65535), 1)
    fG = np.round(np.clip((fG / (2**14)), 0, 65535), 1)
    fB = np.round(np.clip((fB / (2**14)), 0, 65535), 1)

    return fR, fG, fB
```

---

[3] Correct pipeline, using the same conversion coefficients:

```py
def yuv2rgb_ffmpeg_full_float_pipeline_correct(pY, pU, pV, fullRange, depth):

    # Coefficients for ITU-R BT.2020 NCL
    # libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_coeffs:58 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    crv, cbu, cgu, cgv = 110013, 140363, 12277, 42626
    fcrv = crv / 65536
    fcbu = cbu / 65536
    fcgu = cgu / 65536
    fcgv = cgv / 65536

    # Equivalent to libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:813 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fcy = 1.0
    foy = 0.0

    # Equivalent to libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:817 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    if not fullRange:
        fcy = (fcy * 255) / 219
        foy = 16.0 * 65535 / 255.0
    else:
        fcrv = (fcrv * 224) / 255
        fcbu = (fcbu * 224) / 255
        fcgu = (fcgu * 224) / 255
        fcgv = (fcgv * 224) / 255

    # Equivalent to libswscale\yuv2rgb.c:ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables:811 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fcgu = -fcgu
    fcgv = -fcgv

    # Equivalent to libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2389 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY = float(-128) * 65535 / 255
    fU = float(-128) * 65535 / 255
    fV = float(-128) * 65535 / 255

    # Equivalent to libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2394 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY += pY * 65535 / (2**depth-1)
    fU += pU * 65535 / (2**depth-1)
    fV += pV * 65535 / (2**depth-1)

    # Equivalent to libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2402 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY += float(128) * 65535 / 255

    # Equivalent to libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2417 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fY -= foy
    fY *= fcy

    # Equivalent to libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2420 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fR = fY + fV*fcrv
    fG = fY + fV*fcgv + fU*fcgu
    fB = fY +           fU*fcbu

    # libswscale\output.c:yuv2gbrpf32_full_X_c:2424 (ffmpeg 5.1.2)
    fR = np.round(np.clip(fR, 0, 65535), 1)
    fG = np.round(np.clip(fG, 0, 65535), 1)
    fB = np.round(np.clip(fB, 0, 65535), 1)

    return fR, fG, fB
```

Comment: "has the disadvantage that it requires to set the YUV to RGB matrix"  so does scale, ideally you should always specify both input and output matrix or obly one of them if rgb is involved.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it! `zscale` requires `-colorspace` to be set, while `scale` assumes an old standard by default for compatibility, and that's why my toy example wasn't working ; I think both pieces of the puzzle are here now : zscale does seem to provide the correct transformations, provided you a) specify yourself the default matrix if there isn't any, which is perfectly reasonable and b) always output to `gbrp16le` before converting to the target pixel format (which I assume uses `swscale`'s RGB to RGB conversions). If you're inclined to write an answer I'll accept it!